# Problems setting a TcpClient local endpoint in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

Why won't the following code work in C#?

```
var c1 = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8787));
var c2 = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8788));
c1.Connect("localhost", 8788);
```

I get a "connection cannot be made because the target machine actively refused it". So, the TcpClient constructor doesn't appear to be binding the port, but I tried the Socket.Bind() function with no luck either.

Comment: Are you meaning to run a 'server' on port 8788?

Comment: It's more a of a peer to peer thing, so neither of them is the server. Due to the nature of the program I need to specify the local port as well (can't just have it set to any and get randomized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two `TcpClient`'s can't talk to each other.  You need one `TcpClient` and one `TcpListener`.

Comment: TcpListener: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

Comment: Is there any simpler way? I don't need to accept more than a single connection. Is a TcpClient simply not able to respond to a SYN?

Comment: @Nayruden, no, `TcpClient` can't accept a connection.  To communicate you need a client and a server.  Client connects to server.  If you're really talking about always communicating on the same computer, inter-process-communication, then there are a bunch of options on how to do IPC, but TCP is still very common and one of the simplest methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not listening for connections.  You have to use a TcpListener or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sam. You can find an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/tcpclientserver.aspx).